# MP3 file seek is bugged

Tags: vlc-media-player, mp3, media-player

I face an issue with certain MP3 files downloaded from YouTube, which get somehow corrupted.

When I try to seek using the seekbar of a Media Player before 30 seconds it just restarts the MP3, while the timeline says we are at 0:25. So it gets offset.

While Windows Media Player has this bug VLC, on the other hand, works fine. So there is a workaround to that I'm sure.

My question is: Is there any workaround to somehow recover it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file is not indexed properly. Why this happens on your downloads I cannot know but VLC is smart enough to reindex the file on the fly. The solution is to "convert" it to... well, you can convert it to mp3 again and it should be fixed. You can use an online mp3 converter or many of the free software available for that.

Comment: yeah I used vid2mp3 and all file downloaded from that site reproduces this issue. At first i thought it's the bitrate as 320 kbps things were working fine (but they were just from a different website)

Comment: So use a different site. I won't even paste links because if you Google mp3 convert online, you'll get hundreds of results.

Comment: Thanks you answer saved me from this ever lasting headache

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:
www.youtube-mp3.org?

It works pretty good as long as the video isn't more than 20 minutes. I typically look for songs with lyrics as these are usually posted by individuals rather than a service like Vevo. This helps to avoid commercials and result in pretty good audio quality provided the posted video has decent audio quality to begin with.

Just copy the URL, paste it into the box and click convert, then click download and choose where you want to save the file.

Comment: You are proposing an alternate way to download MP3 music from YouTube instead of presenting a work around to enable to play the bugged tracks in Windows Media Player